# Trying to validate double as only numbers

Tags: c++

I just started C++ and need some help.

Basically, my code is working the way I want. However, as you can see below, when I type a number and a letter, the code still counts the variable as only a number.

I want the same error message that displays when someone types a letter then a number the same way for this. I know it has something to do with my function, but when I tried doing `isNaN(Not-a-Number)` the same problem occurred. What am I doing wrong?

I have included my code for the functions validation where the problem is:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double getNumber(){
    double temperature = 0;
    while (cout << "Please enter a temperature between -40 and 40 degrees Celsius: " && !(cin>>temperature))
    {  
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cin.fail();
        cout << "Bad value, try again..." << endl;
        cout <<"\n";
    }

    return temperature;
}

double validRange(double min, double max){
    double temperature = 0;
    while(true){
        temperature = getNumber();
        if(temperature >= min && temperature <= max)
            break;
        else
        {
           cout << "Out of range, value must be between " << min << " and " << max << endl;
        }
    }
    return temperature;
}
```

Comment: Post actual code, not links to images

Comment: Would you please post actual code so I can edit those to suggest an answer?

Comment: A `double` is already numeric. What you are trying to validate (and convert?) is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the validity of the input, I would suggest utilizing stod() and exception handling. Because `cin` takes as many expressions that can be interpreted to number as possible, and returns nonzero value if that happened. However, `stod()` can check the number of characters that was parsed, and if we check whether whole expression is parsed, and if not, `throw`, we can perform the validity check. Here's the modified getnumber():

```
double getNumber() {
    double temperature;
    bool got_the_value = false;
    while (!got_the_value) {
        try {
            cout << "Please enter a temperature between -40 and 40 degrees Celsius: ";
            string tmpstring;
            cin >> tmpstring;
            size_t pos;
            temperature = stod(tmpstring,&pos);
            if (tmpstring.size() != pos) {
                cerr << "Bad value, try again..." << endl;
                continue;
            }
            got_the_value = true;
        }
        catch (exception& e) {
            cerr << "Bad value, try again..." << endl;
        }
    }
    return temperature;
}
```

Comment: If you are checking it by try-catch in this scope, would not it be better to have a condition that throws exception considering the other factors such as range and letter by number?

Comment: Oh wait, I noticed that stod does not catches the errorneous input when the digit is preceded. I have to modify it again.

Answer (score 1):

User input is always a pain. You should:

- get a *string* from the user
- convert the *entire* string to what you want
- abort on fail (with error message)

I keep a little function around for just this purpose:

```
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto string_to( const std::string & s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  return ((ss >> value) and (ss >> std::ws).eof())
    ? value
    : std::optional<T> { };
}
```

It can be used as:

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Please enter a temperature between -40 and 40: ";
  std::string s;
  getline( std::cin, s );
  auto temperature = string_to <double> ( s );
  if (!temperature or (*temperature < -40) or (*temperature > 40))
  {
    std::cerr << "That was not a valid temperature.\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Good job!\nYou entered " << *temperature << "°.\n";
}
```

You can even wrap common code (like asking for a number in a certain range of values) up into a little function if you intend to use it a lot:

```
#include <ciso646>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

double ask_for_number(
  const std::string & prompt,
  double minimum,
  double maximum,
  const std::string & error_message )
{
  std::cout << prompt;
  std::string s;
  getline( std::cin, s );
  auto number = string_to <double> ( s );
  if (!number or (*number < minimum) or (*number > maximum))
  {
    std::cerr << error_message << "\n";
    exit( 1 );
  }
  return *number;
}

int main()
{
  double temperature = ask_for_number(
      "Please enter a temperature between -40 and 40: ",
      -40, 40,
      "That was not a valid temperature." );
  std::cout << "Good job!\nYou entered " << temperature << "°.\n";
}
```

It seems like a lot of typing, but the point is that all the typing goes in one spot and it can be reused over and over and over, *and* it works correctly, expecting the user to provide a single input for a single prompt and properly failing on invalid input.

Comment: Why is `!temperature` an invalid temperature?

Comment: Because `temperature` (in the second snippet, or `number` in the third snippet) is a `std::optional` — it is how you check that it contains a value. Also, `<ciso646>` is required by the Standard to be included if you use operator synonyms.

Comment: It seems like that check doesn't quite cut it [example](https://godbolt.org/z/K9csTj7s7). No, including `ciso646` is not required. It's even been removed since C++20. It was a compatibility header that did "nothing" (since everything in it is covered by C++ keywords). I suggest that you rollback the rollback.

Comment: [It is still required for older compilers or standards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646). C++17 is a _very_ reasonable standard to be using today. When we hit 2023 I will consider the change.

Comment: _"In old or nonconforming compilers, using the alternative operator representations may still require including this header."_ - This is hardly a reason to include it. If anyone uses a compiler where these are _not_ keywords, they have portability issues beyond belief already. Please do not promote including that header.

Comment: We seem to be at a logical disconnect. Many people today are _necessarily_ using older compiler systems. I think it reasonable to expect a minimum of C+17, but people with real-world business concerns, like [Amazon, for example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp), still use C++11. Again, I will reconsider removing stuff that the real-world _requires_ in at minimum another year.

Comment: You do realize that it's not the C++ standard that is referenced? They were keywords in C++98 too, and as you mention, the rest of your answer requires C++17. The logical disconnect is, i.m.o., including a header that's been removed from the standard library, in order to support compilers that can't possibly be C++17 compliant, which the rest of your answer relies upon.